# Nginx troubles on setting a remote validator node

Tags: peers, nginx

So my node requires port 30333 to peer with other nodes, and since I am using Nginx on the server, I followed this guide : https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-setup-a-validator-with-reverse-proxy.

In this guide there's one code block like this :

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:2435;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:30333;
  }
}
```

which gives me the following issue :

```
nginx[83369]: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/streams-enabled/polkadot-proxy.conf:3
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `server` block should be inside the `http` block.

Here is some details around it for the exact same error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392741/nginx-errorlocation-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-etc-nginx-nginx-conf76